# Cucumber CPP Build Error : is_initialized() is not a member of unit test

Tags: c++, boost, cucumber-cpp

I am trying to learn how to use Cucumber CPP. I have been initially following the steps [here](http://infowarestudios.co.za/agile-testing-getting-agile-tests-incorporated-into-your-sprints-using-bdd-and-cucumber-in-c/). But I ran into some errors with it. Currently, I am trying to follow the steps [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cukes/2YlmfBwhFow). When I try to build Cucumber-CPP.sln in Visual Studio 2015, it gives me the below errors:

```
C:\Cucumber-CPP\tests\integration\drivers\BoostDriverTest.cpp(49): error C2039: 'is_initialized': is not a member of 'boost::unit_test::framework'
c:\Boost\boost/test/tree/test_unit.hpp(44): note: see declaration of 'boost::unit_test::framework'
C:\Cucumber-CPP\tests\integration\drivers\BoostDriverTest.cpp(49): error C3861: 'is_initialized': identifier not found
C:\Cucumber-CPP\tests\integration\drivers\BoostDriverTest.cpp(51): error C2039: 'is_initialized': is not a member of 'boost::unit_test::framework'
c:\Boost\boost/test/tree/test_unit.hpp(44): note: see declaration of 'boost::unit_test::framework'
C:\Cucumber-CPP\tests\integration\drivers\BoostDriverTest.cpp(51): error C3861: 'is_initialized': identifier not found
```

Because of these errors, I think its not building *BoostCalculatorSteps.exe* which is required for the next step in the tutorial. I can't find out what I am missing. Please give me your suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

is_initialized() is deprecated in the latest Boost (v1.59, see [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_34_0/libs/optional/doc/optional.html)). The recommended Boost version for the current Cucumber v0.3 release is v1.55. Unfortunately, the latest CMake didn't detect Boost v1.55. When I tried one of the older versions of CMake, it didn't detect VS 2015. So, I couldn't progress further.